# ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 5 layers into a model with 0 layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have been searching to find an answer to this problem in the past few days, no luck.

Just training a simple `CNN`, an saving the `weights` and also the `model`.

While loading the `model` and `weights`, i receive the error saying :

> ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 5 layers into a model with 0 layers.

I have used this before without any issue, long time a go. But all new attempts to load the model fails.

Can you help?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Please include the rest of your code.